# Analyzing arrays without known array size

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java.util.scanner

I've been searching around for an answer and I've always found things that have partially answered my issue. So, this is my code for now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VelikaDN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
        int[] array = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            // Number of elements
            int counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[j] != 0)
                    counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("This array has " + counter + " numbers.");
        }
    }
}
```

It works but at the end I've noticed something that wasn't so minor as I thought it was. This is the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5nsO.png
I've tried to reposition the print all over the code, tried to somehow stop the loop but I failed. I'm really not even sure anymore what is the issue. I tried to let go of this issue and do another task but as I've already said, anything outside the loop is not showing up.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I'm new at Java and I'm also pretty bad at explaining. If you have some tips or an alternate solution, feel free to just toss it in here. If there is something else I need to explain, then just say so.

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: This is just the beginning of the program I'm doing and for now this is the issue, yes. However, when I tried to use array.length outside the first for loop I wasn't able to.

Comment: The loop will end when you have entered **100** numbers!!!

Comment: Andreas I think that he counts only numbers different than 0. Or that is what it looks like

Comment: @VelkoGeorgiev The outer `for` loop will run 100 times, each taking one number from the `Scanner`, waiting for more input as needed. So after the 3 numbers entered, it is sitting there waiting on more numbers, and will not exit until 100 numbers have been processed.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But I thought that the idea is to read a 100 numbers and show the amount of numbers different of 0. ( The second loop is out of the topic :D )

Comment: @VelkoGeorgiev The problem is that OP *"tried to somehow stop the loop but failed"*. My answer: The loop will end when you have entered 100 numbers.

Comment: LoL tnx @Andread I've missed that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see the point of using 2 nested for loops (or 2 separate loops), its just making the algorithm complexity O(n^2)
You can check if the value is 0 in the first loop and if its not incremet the value of the counter

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
    int[] array = new int[2];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();

        if(array[i] != 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("This array has " + counter + " numbers.");
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
    int[] array = new int[100];
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < array.length; i++) {
        int inputValue = input.nextInt();

        if(inputValue <= 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            array[i] = inputValue;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("This array has " + i + " numbers.");
}
```

**EDIT 2 (Credit @Andreas)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
    int[] array = new int[100];
    int i = 0;

    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        int inputValue = input.nextInt();

        array[i++] = inputValue;
    }

    System.out.println("This array has " + i + " numbers.");
}
```

Comment: Right, I'm an idiot. Is there a way of making this work if I for example I set int[] array = new int[100] (the 100 being a maximum) and then the user can input a "random" amount of numbers?

Comment: Are you familiar with ArrayLists ?

Comment: By the way as @Andreas said it the question comment, this loop will always ask for 100 numbers, you can put some condition to avoid that. For example if the introduced number is less or equal to 0 you can break/exit from the for loop.

Comment: Before `input.nextInt()`, insert `if (! input.hasNextInt()) break;`.

Comment: Check the edit. Is an example. If your input is less or equal to 0 the for loop will stop

Comment: Alright, the first edit returned 0 after I've entered a 0 or a negative but the second edit nothing.

Comment: The second one you must type something different than a number or white space. (Letter for example)

Answer (score 1):

Put `int counter=0;` outside the loop and then post the system.out after the loop

Comment: Stuck in what? On the other hand you can just use ArrayList it can give you the array size and much more

Comment: It only prints out the first print statement.

Comment: The print statement should be after the second loop